# Define a $4 \times 4$ operator matrix so that pre-multiplying any matrix $X$ with this matrix will result in...

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

addition of $c_i$ times the $i$th row of $X$ to the $2$nd row of $X$ for each $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in one shot. Additionaly, Show that this matrix can be expressed as the product of three elementary addition matrices and a single elementary multiplication matrix.

My attempt:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ c & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & c & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ c & 1 & c & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I am unsure about the part for $i \in 2$ (would it just be a $1+c$ in the $(2,2)$ position of the matrix?) or how to express it as a product of three elementary addition matrices and a multiplication matrix.

**SOURCE**: Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning (page 23, problem 1.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the problem. You need to find $M(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4)$ such that for any matrix $X=x_{i,j},\ i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ you get $MX=Y$, where $Y=y_{i,j}$. If $i\ne 2$ then $y_{i,j}=x_{i,j}$. If $i=2$ then $$y_{2,j}=c_1x_{1,j}+(1+c_2)x_{2,j}+c_3x_{3,j}+c_4x_{4,j}$$
Once you write explicitly the $M$, $X$, and $Y$ matrices you can proceed in two ways. First (the easy one) is to write the $MX$ product, to check what properties does $M$ have. The more complicated way is to invert $X$, then write $M=YX^{-1}$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine that rows of $X$ are simply numbers: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c_1 & 1+c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ X_3 \\ X_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 + (c_1X_1+c_2X_2+c_3X_3+c_4X_4) \\ X_3 \\ X_4 \end{bmatrix}$$